# how to remove google ads conversion action that cannot be removed because it is used for optimization at the campaign-level

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-analytics-firebase, activecampaign

I am trying to integrate **firebase** into **google ads account** to track installation conversions from the app , i unknowingly used the **first_open (ios)** for the staging app while i need it on production app , i can't import the one for the production since they are both considered the same conversion action

```
 You've imported 0 app conversion actions from Google Analytics (GA4)
    Important next steps:
 warning
    The following Firebase event(s) couldn't be imported,
    because you already have conversion action(s) 
    tracking the same conversion event for
    the same app: (iOS) First open
```

, and can't remove the one already exists , it fails with this error message :

```
This conversion action cannot be removed because it is used for optimization at the campaign-level.
```

also when trying to Change conversions setting it says :

```
Cannot edit campaign conversions setting for a UAC campaign.
```

any idea or suggestion would be great

Comment: Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution as well.